# Properties.Settings.Default.YourConnectionString

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have value

> Properties.Settings.Default.YourConnectionString

Where in the Settings of application I can see this value? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>` node was added properly to `App.config` or `Web.config` you should see the connection string inside project's Properties → Settings.
It will even prompt you when you visit it after adding connection string that it added some new data automatically to your Settings view.
If you can't find it, check if YourConnectionString has been added properly in `App/Web.config`.